# Child div not aligning itself to another div inside a parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble getting #divSocial to align itself inline with #divNavMenu. I've tried to float to the right, but all that does is expand the parent div, #divNavigation vertically and take those social icons down another line. It's probably some small piece of code, but I've been fuzzing with it for quite some time.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title>Tutorials Index Page</title>
<link href="../css/tutorialHelp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="divHeaderContainer">
<div id="divHeader">
<div id="divLogo"></div>
<div id="divNavigtation">
<div id="divNavMenu">
<ul>
<li> <a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="../Tutorials/index.html">Tutorials</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="../Photoshop/index.html">Photoshop</a>
<li><a href="../Dreamweaver/index.html">Dreamweaver</a>
<li><a href="../Illustrator/index.html">Illustrator</a>
<li><a href="../Flash/index.html">Flash</a>
<li><a href="../InDesign/index.html">InDesign</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="../Articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="../About/index.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="../Contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end main UL -->
<br class="clearFloat" />
</div>
<div id="divSocial">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tutorialhelp/497024140318879" target="_blank"><img title="FacebookIcon" alt="FacebookIcon" src="../images/facebook.png" /></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/Tutorial_Help" target="_blank"><img title="TwitterIco" alt="TwitterIcon" src="../images/twitter.png" /></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="divContentContainer">
<div id="divWrapper">
<div id="divInnerWrapper">
<div id="divContent">
<div id="divBanner"></div>
<h2>Tutorials Index Page</h2>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/photoshopBasicsImage.jpg" alt="PhotoshopBasicsImage" title="PhotoshopBasicsImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Photoshop</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Photoshop</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by James Owen
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">The Basics Of Photoshop</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="Building A Basic Web Page In Dreamweaver">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/dreamweaverBasicWebPageImage.jpg" alt="DreamweaverBasicWebPageImage" title="DreamweaverBasicWebPageImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Dreamweaver</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Dreamweaver</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by James Owen
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">Building A Basic Web Page In Dreamweaver</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="Designing A Cartoon Environment">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/flashCartoonEnvironmentImage.png" alt="FlashCartoonEnvironmentImage" title="FlashCartoonEnvironmentImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Flash</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Flash</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by James Owen
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">Designing A Cartoon Environment</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divBottomBanner"></div>
</div>
<div id="divSidebar">
<div id="divInnerSideBar">
<div id="divAdWrapper">
<div class="adListing"><span>Advertise Here</span></div>
<div class="adListing"><span>Advertise Here</span></div>
<div class="adListing"><span>Advertise Here</span></div>
<div class="adListing"><span>Advertise Here</span></div> 
<br class="clearFloat" />  
</div>
<div id="divDonate">
<h3>Support This Web Site!</h3>
<span>Donate to help the cost of running this site.</span>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function validateAmount(amount){
    if(amount.value.match( /^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?$/)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('You must enter a valid donation.');
        amount.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form action="https://checkout.google.com/cws/v2/Donations/701849125270859/checkoutForm" id="BB_BuyButtonForm" method="post" name="BB_BuyButtonForm" onSubmit="return validateAmount(this.item_price_1)" target="_top">
    <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="Donations for Site"/>
    <input name="item_description_1" type="hidden" value="Donate for the cost of running the site."/>
    <input name="item_quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input name="item_currency_1" type="hidden" value="USD"/>
    <input name="item_is_modifiable_1" type="hidden" value="true"/>
    <input name="item_min_price_1" type="hidden" value="0.01"/>
    <input name="item_max_price_1" type="hidden" value="25000.0"/>
    <input name="_charset_" type="hidden" value="utf-8"/>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="1%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" width="1%">&#x24; <input id="item_price_1" name="item_price_1" onfocus="this.style.color='black'; this.value='';" size="11" style="color:grey;" type="text" value="Enter Amount"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" width="1%">
                <input alt="Donate" src="https://checkout.google.com/buttons/donateNow.gif?merchant_id=701849125270859&amp;w=115&amp;h=50&amp;style=trans&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US" type="image"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="divSpacer"></div>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tutorialhelp/497024140318879" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    min-width:1300px;
    background-color:#83ACBC;
}

#divHeaderContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#CEDBD9;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#divHeader{
    width:1120px;
    height:200px;
    min-width:1120px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r1_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

#divLogo{
    height:130px;
    background-image:url(../images/tutorialHelp.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    

}

#divNavigation{
    height:32px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#333;
    width:1120px;
}

#divNavMenu {
    width:900px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#divNavMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}

#divNavMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#DCE4E3;
}

#divNavMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
    width:148px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #C5D1D0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divNavMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
}

#divNavMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:9999; 
}

#divNavMenu li:hover {
   background:#83ACBC;
}

#divNavMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#9EBECB;
}

#divNavMenu a:hover {   
    color:#FFF;
} 

/* Contains the Float */

.clearFloat {
    clear:both; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* IE7 Display Fix */  

#divNavMenu ul li {

    display: inline;     

}   

#divContentContainer{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r3_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

#divWrapper{
    width:1120px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r2_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
}

#divInnerWrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1088px;
}

#divContent{
    width:738px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#divBanner{
    width:700px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
}

#divListing{
    padding:20px 20px 0px 18px;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.listing{
    height:auto;
    background:none;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #B7B7B7;
}

#divListingLeft{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#divListingRight{
    width:480px;
    float:right;
}

.metaWrapper{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}

.tags{
    font-style:italic;
}

.date{
    font-style:italic;
}

#divContent #divListing p{
    padding:0 20px 0px 10px;
}

#divContent #divListing h1{
    font-size:26px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 10px;
    margin:0px;
}

h1 a{
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

#divBottomBanner{
    width:700px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
}

h2{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #B7B7B7;
    color: #FAA221;
}

#contactForm{
    padding:0px;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divSidebar{
    float:right;
    width:337px;
}

#divInnerSideBar{
    width:300px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#divAdWrapper{
    width:260px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 23px;
}

.adListing{
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    margin: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}

.adListing span{
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    margin:56px auto;
    color:#83ACBC;
}

#divSpacer{
    display:block;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#divDonate{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#divDonate h3{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#divDonate span{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#divAboutBio{
    padding:20px 20px 0px 18px;
}

#divAboutBio ul li{
    font-weight:bold;
}

#divSocial{
    float:right;
    height:32px;
    width:100px;
    display:block;

}
```

I've added both HTML and CSS and hopefully you will see where the problem(s) lay in the code. The goal is to have the #divNavigation have #divNavMenu on the left and #divSocial and on the right but on the same alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:left;` to `#divNavMenu`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure as to why float:left to #divNavMenu needed to be there but it works.

Answer (score 0):

try putting float:left; for divNavMenu and divSocial:

```
#divNavMenu{
    float:left;
    width:900px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#divSocial{
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: float:left  o the divNavMenu worked on putting the #divSocial on the same alignment. I don't quite understand why it needed the float there, but it worked wonders. Thanks!

Comment: I think without floating a div tag, even if you assign a certain width it consumes an entire line of space. So when you were floating the social div to the right, it does goes to the right but a line below where the nav div was. Np, ran with same problem ages ago took me hours to figure.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your code. In the div #divSidebar, you are telling (float:right), float will work after assigning the position:absolute property only. try this code.

```
#divSidebar{
    width:337px;
    position:absolute;
    top:138px;
    right:175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style

```
#divNavMenu {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
#divNavigation {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

displaying both #divNavMenu div and #divNavigation div as inline-block is better than the use of float and clear